# Synchronize token request in nodejs node cluster

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, synchronization

So I have this situation, where I need to get a token from one server and then use it in my other methods.

Only first request should download the token and store it somewhere, so no more requests would be made, unless token has expired.

The problem is, that every request now tries to generate token, invalidating old ones and other parallel requests fail.

How should this case be addressed in nodejs environment consisting of separate nodejs nodes and load balancer?

So far I can think of two ways:

1. Intermediate server which would handle downloading token and providing it to calling nodes, thus handling the synchronization.
2. Cron job which keeps some database field updated.

Comment: Since the server is running on cluster mode add this check if(process.env.NODE_APP_INSTANCE == 0) to see the id of the cluster instance. Clustered running node servers have their id you can match the id and run your code only from a specific cluster.

Answer (score 0):

I would take the first solution. A node server as a service holding common data building a small api serving what is needed by other services.